# F# - constructing nested types

Tags: f#, composite

I guess this is pretty basic F# question:

Types are:

```
type Id1 =
    | Id1 of int

type Id2 =
    | Id2 of string

type Id =
    | Id1
    | Id2

type Child = {
    Id : Id;
    Smth : string list
    }

type Node =
    | Child of Child
    | Compos of Node * Node
```

where `Node` and `Child` should represent replacement for Composite OOP design pattern.

The problem is that I cannot instantiate types in this way:

```
let i1 : Child = {Id = Id1(1); Smth = []}   //Id1 value is not a function and cannot be applied
let i2 : Child = {Id = Id1(1); Smth = []}   //same
let i3 : Node = Compos(i1, i2)  //Expression expected Node but has Child
```

where compiler errors are given in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your definition of `Id` has the same semantics as the following:

```
type T = int | string
```

Such type, which is just a mix of two other types, is commonly referred to as "non-discriminated union". To be fair, there are languages that support non-discriminated unions (e.g. TypeScript), but F# is not one of them. F# is part of the ML family of languages, which support *discriminated* unions. The "discriminated" part there means that the parts of the union need to be given a distinguishing property, a "discriminator", which is more commonly called "constructor". For example:

```
type T = X of int | Y of string
```

Here, `X` and `Y` are *constructors* of type `T`. They are used when constructing values to tell which variant is being constructed:

```
let t = X 42
```

And they are used during pattern matching to tell which variant is expected:

```
let f t = match t with
    | X n -> printfn "it's a number: %d" n
    | Y s -> printfn "it's a string: %s" s
```

You actually have one of those in your own code - `Node`, - so it baffles me a bit why you made this mistake with `Id`, but not with `Node`.

If you want to construct values of `Id` the way you do in the definition of `i1` and `i2` - i.e. `Id1(1)`, - then you need to make `Id` a discriminated union with one of the constructors named `Id1` and taking an `int` as parameter. From the rest of your code I can *guess* that the other constructor should be `Id2` and take a `string`:

```
type Id = Id1 of int | Id2 of string
```

---

Now, an interesting thing to note is that, while my example type `T` above wouldn't compile, your type `Id` compiles just fine. Why is that?

The reason is that `int` and `string` have the wrong capitalization (union case identifiers must be uppercase), but `Id1` and `Id2` are fine in that respect. When you define your type as `type Id = Id1 | Id2`, that is perfectly legal, but those `Id1` and `Id2` have no relation to the previously defined types `Id1` and `Id2`. They just happen to have the same name, and having the same name as previous definitions is allowed in F#. It is called "shadowing".

Your type `Id` ended up having two constructors, `Id1` and `Id2`, both of which have no parameters. This is why the compiler complains when you're trying to pass `1` as parameter to `Id1` as you write `Id1(1)`: "*Id1 is not a function and cannot be applied*"

Comment: `int` and `string` aren't reserved words (they're also functions in the core library after all). That isn't related to the problem, which is only due to multiple DU cases with the same name, as you have mentioned. This should be avoided where possible.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox you're right, I totally messed up that one. Corrected.