# Map generic type to record using pattern matching

Tags: f#

I've a Union type like this:

```ml
type AccountOpenened =
  { Owner: string
    AccountId: Guid
    CreatedAt: DateTimeOffset
    StartingBalance: decimal }

type AccountClosed = { AccountId: Guid }

type AccountEvent = AccountOpenend | AccountClosed
```

I also have a 3rd party library from which I can get `IReadOnlyList<IEvent>` whereas `IEvent` as this signature:

```cs
public interface IEvent {
  object Data { get; }
}
```

The library also provides a generic class `Event<T>` which has this signature:

```cs
public class Event<T> : IEvent {
   public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to map an instance of `IReadOnlyList<IEvent>` to an `AccountEvent list` using exhaustive pattern matching.

I tried something like this:

```ml
let map (input: IEvent): AccountEvent =
  match input with
  | :? (Event<AccountOpened>) as e ->
      { Owner = e.Data.Owner
        AccountId = e.Data.AccountId
        CreatedAt = e.Data.CreatedAt
        StartingBalance = e.Data.StartingBalance }

  | :? (Event<AccountClosed>) as e ->
      { AccountId = e.Data.AccountId }
  | _ -> failwith "Unknown Event"
```

This doesn't work because I get this compiler error:

```
This expression was expected to have type 'AccountEvent' but here has type 'AccountCreation'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to specify the constructor e.g. `(Event<AccountClosed>) as e ->
      AccountClosed { AccountId = e.Data.AccountId }`

Comment: F# does not have undiscriminated union types.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58071477/180286

Comment: @Lee Thanks, this did the trick!

Comment: However the exhaustive check doesn't seem to work correctly. If I remove the `_` case I get an error `Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value '( some-other-subtype )' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).`

Comment: You still need the `_` case since object hierarchies are open so there could be another `IEvent` subtype that isn't handled.